# Web browser that does not respect X-Frame-Options?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, google-chrome, browser

I am looking for a web browser that does not respect the X-Frame-Options header, so that I can show websites inside iframes that send "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" headers.

Thanks

Comment: Take note - this is my website that I am displaying. I want to be able to do it myself, but I do not want other people to.

Answer (score 0):

MDN has a [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options). It looks like support for SAMEORIGIN was added in Chrome 4.1.249.1042, Firefox 3.6.9 (1.9.2.9), IE 8.0, Opera 10.5, and Safari 4.0. Showing someone else's website in a iframe when they are sending X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN headers doesn't sound very ethical though, supported by the browser or not. Also be aware that the iframe has the ability to redirect the parent page with JavaScript, or do other unpleasant things if it detect it is in a frame.